# Можно ли как-нибудь сделать на html сайте бегущую строку, которая будет показывать время и дату?

Tags: html, css, svg

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать на html сайте бегущую строку, которая будет показывать время и дату?

Comment: Можно, но для времени и даты, уже понадобиться + JavaScript. Добавь свои наработки в вопрос.

Comment: если Вам помог ответ и он является решением Вашего вопроса, [отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), если же нет, то напишите больше подробностей для получения более качественного ответа.

Answer (score 7):

Без javascript дату и время получить и отображать нельзя.
Пример ниже использует javascript для вывода даты и времени:

```js
const ar_month = ["января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля", "мая", "июня", "июля", "августа", "сентября", "октября", "ноября", "декабря"];

setInterval(function() {
  Data = new Date();
  Year = Data.getFullYear();
  Month = Data.getMonth();
  Day = Data.getDate();
  Hour = Data.getHours();
  Minutes = Data.getMinutes();
  Seconds = Data.getSeconds();

  let datetime = "Сегодня " + Day + " " + ar_month[Month] + " " + Year + " года " + Hour + ":" + Minutes + ":" + Seconds;
  document.querySelector(".marquee-datetime").textContent = datetime;
}, 1000);
```

```css
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-300px, 0)
  }
}

.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee p {
  animation: scroll 10s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <p class="marquee-datetime"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Если ТС знает только HTML/CSS, то этот ответ ему особо понимания не добавит (хотя добавит хотябы в том компоненте, что надо учить JS :))) ), но все равно спасибо за ответ, плюс заслуженно твой.

Comment: @L.F.C. thx) я думаю, что если у ТС будет желание, он разберется. В любом случае последующие аналогичные вопросы уже можно будет закрывать как дубликаты. P.S.: а вообще, в данном вопросе, правильный ответ "нельзя" ))

Comment: switch case в этом случае смотрится убого

Comment: @StrangerintheQ сейчас должно быть лучше)

Answer (score 5):

SVG вариант, для построения пути использовал вот [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/966637/188366), сама дата форматируется `new Date().toLocaleString();`

```js
let pad = 150;
let speed = 0.1
let text = document.querySelector('textPath');
let len = document.querySelector('#path').getTotalLength();
requestAnimationFrame(upd);
let t = 0, v = 0;
function upd(dt) {
    t = dt - t;
    text.textContent = new Date().toLocaleString();
    text.setAttribute('startOffset', (v += t*speed)%(len+pad)-pad);
    t = dt;
    requestAnimationFrame(upd);
}
```

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 660 199">
  <text font-size="25px">
    <textPath href="#path"></textPath>
  </text>
<path id="path" fill="none" d="M26,110C26,110,20.55,41.405,42,26C63.45,10.595000000000002,97.58500000000001,32.56,136,31C174.415,29.44,200.78,18.195,239,18C277.22,17.805,293,30.39,332,30C371,29.61,399.805,16.195,439,16C478.195,15.805,497.12,28.415,533,29C568.88,29.585,601.94,2.620000000000001,623,19C644.06,35.379999999999995,641,113,641,113"></path></svg>
```

PS: не разобрался как сделать через тег `<animate>`, посчитал `startOffset` сам

Comment: `<animate>` [поддерживается не всеми браузерами](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil), поэтому с ним ответ был бы немного хуже

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен нуль перед минутами, если минут меньше 10 (22:9 например, а нужно 22:09). Можете добавить условие:

```
if(Minutes <= 9){
    Minutes = '0' + Minutes;
}
```

Comment: или же воспользоваться [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)