# Как расположить текст полукругом поверх изображения?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как можно сделать как на картинке, текст полукругом поверх изображения?

Comment: Используй svg. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath

Comment: @Arthur можете пожалуйста код написать у меня ничего не получается  :(

Comment: @Alexandr_TT скажите пожалуйста, когда можно увидеть ваш очередной шедевр ?

Comment: сделаю, главное твори маэстро :)

Comment: @user332017, о знакомое с fl, взялись и не можете сделать?!

Comment: @HamSter 1)Все мы учились по немного, Вы же тоже не были всезнающим. 2) Что  же до вашего вопроса я думал тут можно сделать картинкой

Comment: @HamSter  3) насколько я знаю этот сайт создан для вопросов и ответов и какая разница когда и при каких обстоятельствах у меня появился вопрос ?!

Comment: @user332017 "я думал тут можно сделать картинкой", так и сделано картинкой, которая включена в SVG. Поэтому вёрстка не сломается при использовании в любых гаджетах.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  у меня при адаптировании блок с картинкой наезжает

Comment: @Alexandr_TT http://cw09756.tmweb.ru/rasda/

Comment: @user332017 для адаптивности я доработал ответ

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я сделал картинкой она при адаптировании наезжает на текст кторый слева, тут поможет svg правильно ?

Comment: @user332017 возьмите мой код один к одному, теперь это самостоятельный `div` и позиционируйте его, как не делимую составляющую. Если вы хотите внутри видоизменить моё приложение, то неизбежно появятся какие-то побочные эффекты

Comment: @user332017, никто не спорит ... только не видно даже наработок, а только задание - картинка!

Comment: @HamSter  cw09756.tmweb.ru/rasda

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Чтобы получить `Path`, вдоль которых будет размещен текст, необходимо выполнить следующие шаги:

- Ваша картинка имеет размеры `540 х 571px` Для загрузки изображения в
  векторный редактор создаем небольшой SVG файл.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="540" height="571" viewBox="0 0 540 571" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxk8n.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

- В векторном редакторе с помощью инструмента - `Рисовать кривые Безье`
  (цифра 1 на рисунке) добавляем узловые точки по траектории линии
  текста
- Сменяем тип узлов `на автоматически сглаженные`- цифра 2 на рисунке
- Рычагами управления узловых точек добиваемся  нужной формы траектории (цифра 3)

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Сохраняем файл в формате `*.svg` и забираем из него три `, для размещения трёх  полукруглых текстов.

Ниже полный код:

```css
.container {
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 540 571" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<style>
.s0{
 fill:none;
 stroke:red;
}
</style> 
<defs>

  <path id="path1" d="m56.6 503c0 0 60.1 27.1 163.9 29.6 58.6 1.4 186.6-56.6 186.6-56.6M73.2 532.9" class="s0"/>
  <path id="path2" d="m73.2 532.9c0 0 93.4 20.2 147 18.8 81.1-2.2 156.7-42.9 156.7-42.9" class="s0"/>
  <path id="path3" d="m301.2 565.6c0 0 43.3-12.1 63.9-21 19.9-8.6 57-31 57-31" />
  </defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOPOS.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
  
   <text fill="#FFD78E" font-size="18" font-weight="900">
    <textPath xlink:href="#path1">
      "Если что-то и стоит делать, так только то,
    </textPath>
  </text> 
     <text fill="#FFD78E" font-size="18" font-weight="900">
    <textPath xlink:href="#path2">
      что принято считать невозможным"
    </textPath>
  </text>  
  
       <text fill="white" font-size="22" font-weight="900">
    <textPath xlink:href="#path3">
      Оскар Уайлд
    </textPath>
  </text>
  </svg>
 </div>
```

**Update**

Чтобы сделать приложение адаптивным, убрал из шапки файла `width="540" height="571"` и обернул SVG в контейнер , размеры, которого заданы в процентах.

Благодаря этому **приложение адаптивно и работает во всех браузерах, включая `IE`, `Edge`**

### Пример анимации текста

Этот бонус дополняет ответ, чтобы показать, что есть и такая возможность анимации текста.

Основная идея использовать атрибут SVG текста `startOffset` - отступ текста от начала пути, вдоль которого он расположен.
При `startOffset="100%"` текст не виден.

Изменяя этот атрибут от 100% до минимума можно получить анимацию появления текста.

`<animate id="an1"
          attributeName="startOffset"
          begin="img1.mouseover"
          values="100%;1%"
          dur="3s"
          repeatCount="1"
          fill="freeze"
          restart="whenNotActive"/>`

*Анимация начинается при наведении курсора на изображение:*

```css
.container {
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 540 571" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<style>
.s0{
 fill:none;
 stroke:red;
}
</style> 
<defs>

  <path id="path1" d="m56.6 503c0 0 60.1 27.1 163.9 29.6 58.6 1.4 186.6-56.6 186.6-56.6M73.2 532.9" class="s0"/>
  <path id="path2" d="m73.2 532.9c0 0 93.4 20.2 147 18.8 81.1-2.2 156.7-42.9 156.7-42.9" class="s0"/>
  <path id="path3" d="m301.2 565.6c0 0 43.3-12.1 63.9-21 19.9-8.6 57-31 57-31" />
  </defs>
<image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOPOS.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
  
   <text fill="#FFD78E" font-size="18" font-weight="900">
    <textPath xlink:href="#path1" startOffset="100%" >
      "Если что-то и стоит делать, так только то, 
   <animate id="an1"
       attributeName="startOffset"
    begin="img1.mouseover"
    values="100%;1%"
    dur="3s"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive"/>  
  
    </textPath>
  </text> 
     <text fill="#FFD78E" font-size="18" font-weight="900">
    <textPath xlink:href="#path2" startOffset="100%">
      что принято считать невозможным" 
    <animate id="an2"
       attributeName="startOffset"
    begin="an1.end"
    values="100%;1%"
    dur="3s"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive"/> 
    </textPath>
  </text>  
  
       <text fill="white" font-size="22" font-weight="900">
    <textPath xlink:href="#path3" startOffset="100%">
      Оскар Уайлд 
      <animate id="an3"
       attributeName="startOffset"
    begin="an2.end"
    values="100%;1%"
    dur="1s"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive"/> 
    </textPath>
  </text>

  </svg>
</div>
```

- Последовательность выполнения анимаций достигается цепочкой условий в
  атрибуте -

  `begin="an1.end"` Эта запись означает, что вторая анимация начнется
  после окончания первой анимации с `id=an1`
- `restart="whenNotActive"` - защита от повторных запусков анимации,
  пока она не дойдёт до конца.

Comment: :(  да ... (какой-то текст )

Answer (score 9):

Еще можно воспользоваться javascript для этого: =)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<input value="Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." 
       onkeyup="d3.select('textPath').html(this.value)">
<input id="result">
<input type="range" style="width:20%" min="-100" max="100" value="50" onchange="tension(this.value/100)">
<br>
<svg>
 <text>
    <textPath href="#path">
      Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
       <!--animate attributeName="startOffset" 
                 values="-100%;100%" dur="30s" repeatCount="indefinite"/-->
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>

<script>
let points = [[50,50],[300,100],[550,50]];
let dragged = null;
let selected = points[points.length-1];
let line = d3.line().curve(d3.curveCardinal.tension(0.1));
let svg = d3.select("svg");
let path = svg.append("path").datum(points).attr('id', 'path');

svg.on("mousemove", mousemove).on("mousedown", mousedown)
d3.select(window).on("mouseup", mouseup).on("resize", adjustSize);
window.oncontextmenu = () => false;
adjustSize();
redraw();

function adjustSize() {
    let w = window.innerWidth;
    let h = window.innerHeight;
    svg.attr("width", w).attr("height", h)
        .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${w} ${h}`);
}

function redraw() {
    
    svg.select("path").attr("d", line);
    d3.select('input#result').attr('value', svg.select("path").attr('d'))
    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle.knob")
        .data(points, d => d);
        
    circle.exit().remove();
    
    let newNodes = circle.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .classed('knob', true)
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .on("dblclick", deletePoint)
        .on("mousedown", d => redraw(selected = dragged = d))
        .transition()
        .duration(250)
        .attr("r", 6.5);

    circle.merge(newNodes)
        .classed("selected", d => d === selected)
        .attr("cx", d => d[0])
        .attr("cy", d => d[1]);
        
    if (d3.event) {
        d3.event.preventDefault();
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
    }
}

function mousemove() {
    if (!dragged) return;
    let m = d3.mouse(svg.node());
    dragged[0] = m[0];
    dragged[1] = m[1];
    redraw();
}

function mouseup() {
    if (!dragged) return;
    mousemove();
    dragged = null;
}

function deletePoint(d) {
    if (!selected)
        return;
    let i = points.indexOf(selected);
    points.splice(i, 1);
    selected = points.length ? 
        points[i > 0 ? i - 1 : 0] : null;
    redraw();
}

function mousedown() {
    if (d3.event.button !== 0)
        return;
    points.push(selected = dragged = 
                d3.mouse(svg.node()));
    redraw();
}

function tension(v){
 line = d3.line().curve(d3.curveCardinal.tension(v));
 redraw();
}

</script>

<style>
body, svg {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    user-select: none;
}
path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: red;
}
circle {
    stroke: red;
    fill: #fff;
    fill-opacity: .4;
}
.selected {fill: #ff7f0e}
text {font-size:30px}
input {width:100%}
</style>
```

Comment: у меня с hamburger проблемы,  а Вы такой код :)

Comment: @user332017 а я не предлагаю его вставлять, таким онлайн тулом можно воспользоваться чтобы получить path и все, взяв его из отладчика например

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Хорошо бы добавить вывод `path` в textarea.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT сделал что-то такое

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  Отлично. Вижу , что ещё добавил возможность редактировать, добавлять текст

Comment: вот он и генератор кривой - круто ... плюсик от меня

Comment: @MaximLensky да, можно сделать чтобы было можно точки добавлять и удалять и выбор типа интерполяции, может допилю потом

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если кучу точек добавишь то в некотором роде многие редакторы не понадобятся ..я имею виду люстру инкскапе и корел ..

Comment: @MaximLensky добавил возможность точки добавлять и удалять

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  больше одного плюса не смогу поставить ...это круто ...спс

Comment: @MaximLensky да нет проблем, я давно этот шаблон с собой таскаю,ща на codepen еще залью https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/wZzrQQ?editors=0010

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  нажал на Сердечко в codepen

Comment: @Alexandr_TT упс, я не хотел сохранять =) это вызвано вот этим  - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/966874/188366

Comment: Лайк за то, что просили сделать одно, а человек заморочился и сделал генератор.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 чесслово легче один раз написать код, чем 2 раза открывать inkscape

Answer (score 7):

Тут основное ударение на **textPath**

Но для начала открываем любой векторный редактор - в моём случае я открыл inkscape так как очень привык к нему

И рисуем обычный изогнутый path

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее пишем текст , я просто скопипастил заголовок и вставил через text

Зажимаем shift и выделяем и кривую и текст и в меню текст находим пункт Разместить по контуру

Ну и собственно всё - текст кривой

Сохраняем как простой SVG или как Оптимизированный svg

Если что то не ясно я дополню ответ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 493 190" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <g transform="translate(196 2)">

  
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 2 -151 -68)" style="fill:#000000;">
    <textPath xlink:href="#path839">Подскажите как можно сделать так текст?</textPath>
  </text>
  
  <path id="path839" d="m-33 133c98-61 191-147 330-2" style="fill:none"/>
  
 </g>
</svg>
```

Подобный пример т.е отсебячина

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  
  <clipPath id="clip">
     <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60"></circle>
  </clipPath>
  
  <image xlink:href="https://s1.ibtimes.com/sites/www.ibtimes.com/files/styles/full/public/2011/10/06/170130-steve-jobs.jpg" width="230px" height="200px" x="-5px" y="20px" clip-path="url(#clip)"></image>
  
  <path id="path"  d='M 19.654762,150.34524 C 85.850737,213.0562 138.74801,192.65028 188.98809,155.6369' style="fill:none; stroke:none;"></path>
  
  <text style="font-family:serif; font-weight:900; font-size:15px;" x="0" y="40px">
    <textPath xlink:href="#path">
       lorem ipsum sit ammed dollar
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```