# Как добавить узловые точки в генераторе кривых

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, d3.js

Вопрос инициирован [отличным ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/966637/28748) на вопрос по созданию полукруглых надписей в SVG.

*Ниже авторский код генератора кривых:*

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<input value="Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." 
       onkeyup="d3.select('textPath').html(this.value)">
<input id="result">
<svg>
 <text>
    <textPath href="#path">
      Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>

<script>
let points = [[50,50],[300,100],[550,50]];
let dragged = null;
let selected = points[points.length-1];
let line = d3.line().curve(d3.curveCardinal);
let svg = d3.select("svg");
let path = svg.append("path").datum(points).attr('id', 'path');

svg.on("mousemove", mousemove).on("mousedown", mousedown)
d3.select(window).on("mouseup", mouseup).on("resize", adjustSize);
window.oncontextmenu = () => false;
adjustSize();
redraw();

function adjustSize() {
    let w = window.innerWidth;
    let h = window.innerHeight;
    svg.attr("width", w).attr("height", h)
        .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${w} ${h}`);
}

function redraw() {
    
    svg.select("path").attr("d", line);
    d3.select('input#result').attr('value', svg.select("path").attr('d'))
    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle.knob")
        .data(points, d => d);
        
    circle.exit().remove();
    
    let newNodes = circle.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .classed('knob', true)
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .on("dblclick", deletePoint)
        .on("mousedown", d => redraw(selected = dragged = d))
        .transition()
        .duration(250)
        .attr("r", 6.5);

    circle.merge(newNodes)
        .classed("selected", d => d === selected)
        .attr("cx", d => d[0])
        .attr("cy", d => d[1]);
        
    if (d3.event) {
        d3.event.preventDefault();
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
    }
}

function mousemove() {
    if (!dragged) return;
    let m = d3.mouse(svg.node());
    dragged[0] = m[0];
    dragged[1] = m[1];
    redraw();
}

function mouseup() {
    if (!dragged) return;
    mousemove();
    dragged = null;
}

function deletePoint(d) {
    if (!selected)
        return;
    let i = points.indexOf(selected);
    points.splice(i, 1);
    selected = points.length ? 
        points[i > 0 ? i - 1 : 0] : null;
    redraw();
}

function mousedown() {
    if (d3.event.button !== 0)
        return;
    points.push(selected = dragged = 
                d3.mouse(svg.node()));
    redraw();
}

</script>

<style>
body, svg {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    user-select: none;
}
path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: red;
}
circle {
    stroke: red;
    fill: #fff;
    fill-opacity: .4;
}
.selected {fill: #ff7f0e}
text {font-size:30px}
input {width:100%}
</style>
```

- Генератор позволяет добавлять текст и создавать разнообразные формы кривых с помощью перетаскивания узловых точек.
- В `textarea` динамически выводится формула `path`
- Есть возможность добавлять новые узловые точки

  **Можно ли внести некоторые улучшения в функционал генератора?**

  1. Добавить возможность выбора количества знаков после запятой в формуле `path`
  2. Изменить порядок добавления новых узловых точек,- в любое место кривой, а не только в конец её.

Добавляем точку, как бы в середину кривой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но новая точка добавилась в конец кривой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Приложение не работает в `Firefox` на локальном ПК

Comment: *грязный хак*: оставляем две точки, добавляем новую, перемещаем предыдущую

Comment: @Bald код в студию please :)

Comment: максим могу гифку сделать(это ответ слегка продвинутого пользователя чем программиста), ждем ответа от автора указанного ответа.

Comment: так с ходу ничего посоветовать не могу, давно не требовались гифки. а так photoshop точно умеет.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ посмотри попутно, почему на локальном ПК  в `Firefox`не работает Добавил в шапку SVG `viewport` и `viewBox` всё равно не работает, добавлю этот пункт в вопрос

Comment: @StrangerintheQ как в фильме `Мимино` Ты любишь долму?  Нет. Потому что у вас не умеют готовить долму.  В Firefox наиболее точно и правильно отрабатывает спецификацию SVG А Chrome c их нелюбовью SVG, всё больше и больше искажают, упрощают SVG.

Answer (score 4):

Я сделялъ :)

Кликами точки можно добавлять, а даблкликами - удалять.

---

Тут есть несколько фокусов:

1. Определение ближайшей точки к мышке, которая лежит на линии, осуществляется за счет того, что каждый раз когда `<path>` меняется - я строю диаграмму Вороного [`d3.voronoi()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-voronoi) для точек лежащих на получившемся пути с фиксированным шагом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое разбиение можно увидеть если убрать вот этот стиль

```
path.voronoi {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: none;
}
```

и вот в этой строчке поставить 20 а не 2

```
.data(voronoi.polygons(sample(path.node(), 2)))
```

Проверка попадания точки в ячейку диаграммы делает браузер за счет механизма mouseover.

2. Второй фокус - определение между какими опорными точками вставлять вновь добавляемую - 
   решил кое как на коленке, вероятно над этой частью еще стоит подумать. Т.к. придуманные мною костыли не работают для аппроксимаций линий, которые не проходят через опорные точки [`d3.curveBasis`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveBasis) например, по-этому другие типы линий пока что убраны из этой поделки.

Сейчас для генерации кривой по опорным точкам используется алгоритм [`d3.curveCardinal`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveCardinal).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<input value="Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." onkeyup="changeText(this.value)">

<input id="result">

<select style="width:20%;display:none" onchange="changeProperties()">
    <option value="curveCardinal">cardinal</option>
    <option value="curveCardinalClosed">cardinal closed</option>
    <option value="curveBasis">basis</option>
    <option value="curveBasisClosed">basis closed</option>
</select>

<input id="tension" type="range" style="width:20%" min="-100" max="100" value="50" onchange="changeProperties()">

<br>

<svg>
    <text><textPath href="#path"></textPath></text>
    <g class="voronoi"></g>
    <g class="path"><path id="path"></path></g>
    <g class="anchors"></g>
    <g class="sticky"><circle r="3" cx="-100" cy="-100"></circle></g>
</svg>

<style>
  body, svg {
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
      user-select: none;
  }
  path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: red;
  }
  path.voronoi {
      fill: transparent;
      stroke: none;
  }
  circle {
      stroke: red;
      fill: #fff;
      fill-opacity: .4;
      cursor:pointer;
  }
  g.sticky circle {
      fill: none;
      pointer-events:none;
  }
  .selected {
      fill: #ff7f0e;
  }
  text {
      font-size: 30px;
  }
  input {
      width: 100%;
  }
  input[type=range] {
      height:6px;
  }
  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
      height:23px;
  }
</style>

<script>
var voronoi, dragged;

let points = [[50, 50], [300, 100], [550, 50]];

let selected = points[points.length - 1];

let line = d3.line()
             .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

let svg = d3.select("svg");

let path = svg.select("path#path")
              .datum(points);

let stick = d3.select('g.sticky circle');

svg.on("mousemove", mousemove)
   .on("mousedown", mousedown);

d3.select(window)
  .on("mouseup", mouseup)
  .on("resize", adjustSize);

window.oncontextmenu = () => false;
adjustSize(); 
redraw(); 
resample();
changeText();

function adjustSize() {

    let w = window.innerWidth, h = window.innerHeight;
    
    svg.attr("width", w)
       .attr("height", h)
       .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${w} ${h}`);
       
    voronoi = d3.voronoi()
                .x(d => d.x)
                .y(d => d.y)
                .size([w, h])
    resample();
}

function redraw() {

    let datum = path.attr("d", line).attr('d');

    datum = datum.replace(/\d+\.\d+/g, s => parseFloat(s).toFixed())

    path.attr("d", datum)

    d3.select('input#result')
      .attr('value', datum);
    
    var circle = svg.select("g.anchors")
                    .selectAll("circle.knob")
                    .data(points, d => d);

    circle.exit().remove();

    let newNodes = circle.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .classed('knob', true)
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .on("dblclick", deletePoint)
        .on("mousedown", d => redraw(selected = dragged = d))
        .on("mousemove", () => stick.attr('opacity', 0))
        .transition()
        .duration(250)
        .attr("r", 6.5);

    circle.merge(newNodes)
        .classed("selected", d => d === selected)
        .attr("cx", d => d[0])
        .attr("cy", d => d[1]);

    if (d3.event) {
        d3.event.preventDefault();
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
    }
}

function mousemove() {
    if (!dragged) return;
    let m = d3.mouse(svg.node());
    dragged[0] = m[0];
    dragged[1] = m[1];
    redraw();
}

function mouseup() {
    if (!dragged) return;
    mousemove();
    dragged = null;
    resample();
}

function resample() {
    try{
      let samples = sample(path.node(), 2);

      svg.selectAll("path.voronoi").remove()

      svg.select('g.voronoi')
         .selectAll("path.voronoi")
         .data(voronoi.polygons(samples))
         .enter()
         .append("path")
         .attr('class', 'voronoi')
         .attr("d", d =>`M${d.join('L')}Z`)
         .on('mouseover', function(d) {
              let m = d3.mouse(svg.node());
              stick.attr('opacity', dist(m, d.data) < 5 ? 1 : 0)
                .datum({x: d.data.x, y: d.data.y})
                .attr('cx', d => d.x)
                .attr('cy', d => d.y)
         });
     } catch {}
}

function deletePoint(d) {
    if (!selected) return;
    let i = points.indexOf(selected);
    points.splice(i, 1);
    selected = points.length ? points[i > 0 ? i - 1 : 0] : null;
    redraw();
    resample();
}

function mousedown() {
    if (d3.event.button !== 0) return;
    let pt = [stick.datum().x, stick.datum().y];
    let m = d3.mouse(svg.node());
    if (dist(m, pt)<5) {   
        points.splice(calcIndex(pt), 0, selected = dragged = pt)
    } else {
        points.push(selected = dragged = m);    
    }
    redraw();
    resample();
    setTimeout(()=>stick.attr('opacity', 0),100)
}

function dist(p1, p2){
    let x = (p1.x || p1[0]) - (p2.x || p2[0]);
    let y = (p1.y || p1[1]) - (p2.y || p2[1]);
    return Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
}

function calcIndex(pt) {
  let pathNode = path.node();
  let total = pathNode.getTotalLength();
  let index = 1;
  let minDistToAnchorPoint = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  let minDistToStickPoint = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  for (let l = 0; l <= total; l++) {
    let p = pathNode.getPointAtLength(l);
    let distToCurrentAnchorPoint = dist(p, points[index]);
    if (distToCurrentAnchorPoint < minDistToAnchorPoint)  {
        minDistToAnchorPoint = distToCurrentAnchorPoint;
    } else {
        index++
        minDistToAnchorPoint = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    if (dist(p, pt)<2)  
        break;
  }
  return index
}

function changeProperties(){
    let type = document.querySelector('select').value;
    let v = document.querySelector('#tension').value/100;
    type = d3[type];
    type.tension && (type = type.tension(v))
    line = d3.line().curve(type);
    redraw();
    resample();
}

function sample(pathNode, precision) {
  let total = pathNode.getTotalLength();
  let samples = [];
  for (let l = 0; l <= total; l += precision) {
    samples.push(pathNode.getPointAtLength(l));
  }
  return samples;
}

function changeText(text) {
  d3.select('textPath').html(text)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Q Замечательно! А сможешь добавить функцию удаления точек? К примеру, сделал сложный контур и где-то нужно удалить лишний узел, совсем не интересно  рисовать  всё заново. Ну это хотелки. Можно и не делать, если это тянет за собой большие переделки

Comment: @Alexandr_TT так это, даблклик =)

Comment: Благодарю.  Вот прямо все вокруг телепаты :) Надо добавить в описание.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, да глаз замыливается, я давно эту поделку за собой таскаю, вот и привык

Comment: Посмотри, конкурс есть, ответов нет. Может 100 срубишь on Enso - [Display of SVG on Leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53170777/7394871) правда он через час заанчивается, но ответов нет пока и продлевают потом на 12 часов, может успеешь

Comment: @Alexandr_TT сейчас посмотрел - не хочу с этим разбираться, чую там будет засада =) это не просто проблема svg а надо в кишках leaflet ковыряться будет =) да и так то работать  надо =)