# Добавить тень на криволинейную фигуру

Tags: css3, html5, svg

На картинке белый слой отбрасывает на синий тень по своему контуру.Как воплотить это в CSS или в svg, у меня тень получается строго горизонтально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему бы не нарисовать эту тень в фотошопе вместо CSS?

Comment: а белый с синим объединить(2 слоя как один "двуцветный" с этим самым переходом) возможно в фотошопе и воспроизвести в css  без ущерба для остальных эементов

Comment: Что-то я не понял комментария. Сделать два слоя в фотошопе (белый с прозрачной тенью и синий), сохранить две картинки и потом в html+css наложить их друг на друга вроде никто не мешает

Answer (score 2):

Вот простейший вариант с `svg` фильтром, пути рисую [этой тулзой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/967235/188366)

```html
<body style="margin:0; overflow:hidden">
<svg width="700" height="200" style="background-color:#57a9a9">
<filter id="shadow" height="130%">
  <!-- stdDeviation сила размытия -->
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5"/> 
  <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" result="offsetblur"/>
  <feComponentTransfer>
    <!-- slope коэф. количества тени -->
    <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.3"/> 
  </feComponentTransfer>
  <feMerge> 
    <feMergeNode/> 
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </feMerge>
</filter>
<path fill="white" style="filter:url(#shadow)" d="M-100,300L1,93C1,93,44,67,76,66C108,65,170,93,208,85C246,77,288,19,324,16C360,13,407,63,440,65C473,67,510,28,536,29C562,30,591,63,609,71C627,79,654,81,654,81L830,100L830,300"/>
<path fill="white" style="filter:url(#shadow)" d="M-100,300L1,93C1,93,44,67,76,66C108,65,170,90,208,85C246,80,289,35,325,34C361,33,407,78,440,80C473,82,510,48,538,49C566,50,603,82,620,87C637,92,652,82,652,82L930,-100L830,300"/>
</svg>
</body>
```

Comment: надеюсь, теперь вы поняли зачем я меняю обезличенные заголовки на конкретику. Сравните, было - "Вёрстка лендинга" (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT так я не говорю что не надо, надо только меня смутило что реализация в вопросе

Comment: Тень надо исправить на обратную. Белая сторона должна наезжать на синею, присмотрись, белая сторона должна быть, как бы выпуклей, выше

Comment: @Alexandr_TT угу, сейчас на телефоне смотрю и вижу, а на мониторе внизу ее рассматривал, сделаю попозже :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  подрихтовал =)

Comment: Если тебя интересует моё мнение, то конечно стало лучше, но цветная волна смотрится более объёмно, хоть и вдавлена немного темной полоской внутрь.  Попробуй добавить тёмную полоску к белой волне, как на образце у автора. Может ты видел пример картинки балерины, на которую смотришь, - она вращается в одну сторону, другим кажется, что балерина вращается в другую сторону. Вот так и здесь на примере у автора, на какой волне концентрируешь внимание, та и кажется объёмней

Comment: @Alexandr_TT учел твои пожелания =)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать много теней. Конечно, чтобы это реализовать, потребуется немало времени. Но как говорится, примите - распишитесь :)

```css
div {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top:100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #fce25b, #ecc92b);
  box-shadow:
  -70px -10px 50px 10px rgb(139,139,139), -40px -40px 50px 10px rgb(118,118,118),
  20px -20px 50px 10px rgb(138,138,138), 40px 40px 50px 10px rgb(117,117,117);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Думаю, что можно было сделать как-то более правильно, но я к сожалению не верстальщик и это первое что пришло мне на ум.

Answer (score 0):

В css - никак, тень соответствует форме элемента, а у вас элемент прямоугольный (просто часть его прозрачна).

Вариантов два:

- Стребовать с дизайнера / фотошопнуть самому белый слой вместе с тенью.
- использовать SVG и тень задать в нем.

Comment: На самом деле в CSS тоже можно (плевать на форму элемента), но это очень сильно тормозит и я бы не рекомендовал делать на CSS

Answer (score 0):

```css
main {
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  margin: 3em;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(-45deg, red 50%, transparent 50%);
  filter: drop-shadow(8em -2em 3px blue);
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```