# Как примагнитить точку к линии?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Попасть в линию очень тяжело. Подскажите сделать, что кликнув рядом с линией понять, что кликнули рядом и поставить точку на линию? Так же, если мы меняем масштаб, прилипание так же сработало.

```
drawing() {

    this.svg_margin.left = 50;
    this.svg_margin.right = 50;
    this.svg_margin.top = 50;
    this.svg_margin.bottom = 50;

    this.draw_width = this.svg_width - this.svg_margin.left - this.svg_margin.right;
    this.draw_height = this.svg_height - this.svg_margin.top - this.svg_margin.bottom;

    let svg = d3.select('#svg-container')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', this.svg_width)
      .attr('height', this.svg_height)
      .style('border', '3px dashed lightgrey')
      .style('background-color', '#4caf5026');

    const x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, this.draw_width]).range([0, this.draw_width]);
    const y_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([this.draw_height, 0]).range([0, this.draw_height]);

    // Создаём рабочую область
    const svg_work_space = svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'svg-work-space')
      .style('fill', 'transparent');

    const line = d3.line()
      .x((d) => x_scale(d.x))
      .y((d) => y_scale(d.y));

    let points  = [];
    let rect = svg_work_space.append('rect')
      .attr("x", 100)
      .attr("y",100)
      .attr("width",100)
      .attr("height",100)
      .attr("fill",'none')
      .style('stroke-width', 5)
      .attr('stroke', 'green');
    let c = svg_work_space
      .append("circle")
      .attr('cx', 100)
      .attr('cy', 100)
      .attr('fill', 'red')
      .attr('r', 1);


    svg.on('click', function() {

      let new_point = d3.mouse(this);

      let new_coordinate = {
        x: Math.round( x_scale.invert(new_point[0])),
        y: Math.round( y_scale.invert(new_point[1]))
      };

      let line ={
        x1:200,
        y1:100,
        x2:200,
        y2:200,
      };


      points.push(new_coordinate);

      svg_work_space.selectAll("circle")
        .data(points)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr('cx', (d) => x_scale(d.x))
        .attr('cy', (d) => y_scale(d.y))
        .attr('fill', 'red')
        .attr('r', 5);


      // Проверяем принадлежит ли точка стороне
      belongsToTheSide(new_coordinate.x, new_coordinate.y, line);

    });

    function belongsToTheSide(x,y, line) {

      let equation = (x - line.x1)*(line.y2 - line.y1)-(line.x2 - line.x1)*(y-line.y1);

      console.log('equation:',equation);

      if (equation === 0 ) {
        console.log('Точка принадлежит прямой');
        return true;
      } else if ( equation > 0) {
        console.log('Точка находится справа от прямой');
        return false;
      } else if ( equation < 0) {
        console.log('Точка находится слева от прямой');
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот алгоритм работающий через предварительный перебор точек с большИм шагом и последующий поиск в пространстве рядом с найденной точкой, с уменьшением шага.

Этот метод подойдет когда кривая, до которой необходимо искать кратчайшее расстояние, меняется со временем.

Производительность можно сильно повысить, если вешать обработчик не на все окно, а на толстую и полностью прозрачную копию линии, у которой установлена ширина, которая бы Вас устроила в качестве зоны прилипания.

—-

PS: [вот в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/967235/188366) используется другой метод, через разбиение Вороного, и там как раз реализовано добавление точки в линию. Используйте этот метод если кривая не меняется, или меняется не часто.

```js
// максимальная дистанция от мышки до линии при которой будет появляться точка
let d = 20; 

// положение svg-шки на экране
let r = svg.getBoundingClientRect();

// невидимая svg точка, при помощи нее будут происходить трансформации координат, 
// чтобы перевести координаты мыши из системы координат окна в систему координат 
// svg пути(учесть всю иерархию transform-ов), к которому магнитим линию
let pt = svg.createSVGPoint();  

// масштаб
let z = 1; 

addEventListener('mousemove', e => {

  // задаем невидимой точке координаты мыши
  pt.x = e.clientX;
  pt.y = e.clientY;

  // переводим эту точку в систему координат path
  let p = pt.matrixTransform(path.getScreenCTM().inverse());

  // применяем алгоритм поиска ближайшей точки
  p = closestPoint(path, [p.x, p.y]);

  // задаем  координаты найденной точки невидимой точке 
  pt.x = p[0];
  pt.y = p[1];

  // переводим обратно в экранные координаты
  let p2 = pt.matrixTransform(path.getScreenCTM());

  circle.setAttribute('cx', p2.x-r.x)
  circle.setAttribute('cy', p2.y-r.y)
  circle.setAttribute('opacity', p.distance < d/z ? 1 : 0)

  // показываем точку только если расстояние до нее меньше порогового значения
  svg.style.cursor = p.distance < d/z ? 'pointer':'default'
})

// поиск ближайшей точки, принадлежащей линии
function closestPoint(pathNode, point) {

  let pathLen=pathNode.getTotalLength(), precis=8, best, bestLen, bestDist=Infinity;

  // перебираем точки вдоль пути с большИм шагом, находим ту, 
  // до которой минимальное расстояние
  for (let scan, scanLen = 0, scanDist; scanLen <= pathLen; scanLen += precis) 
    if ((scanDist = dist(scan = pathNode.getPointAtLength(scanLen))) < bestDist) 
      best = scan, bestLen = scanLen, bestDist = scanDist;

  precis /= 2;

  // сканируем пространство вблизи найденной точки влево и вправо уменьшая шаг между 
  // пробами, сохраняя на каждой итерации наилучший результат (кратчайшее расстояние)
  while (precis > 0.5) {
    let bef, aft, befLen, aftLen, befDist, aftDist;
    if ((befLen = bestLen - precis) >= 0 && 
        (befDist = dist(bef = pathNode.getPointAtLength(befLen))) < bestDist) 
      best = bef, bestLen = befLen, bestDist = befDist;
    else if ((aftLen = bestLen + precis) <= pathLen && 
             (aftDist = dist(aft = pathNode.getPointAtLength(aftLen))) < bestDist) 
      best = aft, bestLen = aftLen, bestDist = aftDist;
    else 
      precis /= 2;
  }

  best = [best.x, best.y];
  best.distance = Math.sqrt(bestDist);
  return best;

  // евклидово расстояние между точками
  function dist(p) {
    let dx = p.x - point[0], dy = p.y - point[1];
    return dx * dx + dy * dy;
  }
}

addEventListener('wheel', e => {
  z *= 1+0.1*Math.sign(e.deltaY);
  path.setAttribute('transform', `scale(${z})`)
  circle.setAttribute('opacity', 0)
}, false)
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="600" height="175">
<path id="path" fill="none" stroke="red"  d="M25,54C25,54,74,88,97,86C120,84,113,45,138,44C163,43,192,83,217,83C242,83,239,44,260,43C281,42,294,79,317,79C340,79,347,49,371,43C395,37,411,54,432,52C453,50,454,28,473,32C492,36,501,73,522,72C543,71,565,19,577,26C589,33,582,108,582,108" transform="scale(1)"></path>
<circle id="circle" r="5" fill="none" stroke="blue" cx="-10" ></circle>
<svg>
```

Comment: Работает просто супер! Но мне хочется понять, как это работает.  Дайте пожалуйста, хотя бы минимальные комментарии по функции `closestPoint`.

Comment: она перебирает точки на линии при помощи бинарного поиска, и сравнивает расстояние до них, от курсора...

Comment: @Stranger in the 0_o а я ... тоже хочу получить комментарии по такому куску коду e.clientX; где e - объект события; а clientX - -это ширина экрана; правильно я понял что  e.clientX - координаты объекта ?

Comment: @Leks координаты мыши, во время порождения события

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а вы сознательно не ставите `;` или просто забываете?

Comment: @doox911 когда не в браузере пишу и ide подсвечивет - стараюсь ставить, но без фанатизма, иногда для удобства копирования не ставлю, иногда потом  расставляю пропущенные, по настроению

Comment: Все координаты надо пересчитывать с учетом масштаба, попробуйте всегда показывать найденную точку...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а при зуме не работает, подскажите, как сделать чтобы считалось корректно (я про p.distance?)

Comment: @doox911 я уже завтра Вам отвечу, хорошо?)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, спасибо, буду ждать.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, я так понимаю тут тоже коэффициент необходимо использовать? Так как я над линией, а дистанция говорит: `78.57143261216045`

Comment: @doox911 Я изменил ответ, там фокус с  `pt.matrixTransform`, масштабирование колесом

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а можно комментарии к коду что где и как происходит?А то ничего не понятно.

Comment: @Demon__ANT вы про какую часть конкретно, алгоритм поиска или трансформация точек?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ про все части.Вы хорошо отвечаете на вопросы это неоспоримо но жалко что никогда не комментируете свой код .Ибо понять его очень сложно .

Comment: @Demon__ANT комментирую, когда есть время и когда попросят, вот сейчас например:)

Comment: @Demon__ANT это наверное от привычки ковырятся в исходниках, я сам познаю это чаще через код, ибо частенько кроме него ничего больше нет

Comment: @StrangerintheQ тут очень мало разработчиков вашего уровня и было бы отлично всегда комментировать чтобы другие когда смотрели понимали что где и как происходит.Я вот с Js-ом работаю года два но элементарно про существование `/=` этого оператора не знал.И 98% вашего кода тоже не понимаю.Поэтому пожалуйста всегда прокомментируйте свой код чтобы другие включая меня понимали  ваш код.Так как я всегда слежу за вашими ответами.  ;)

Comment: @Demon__ANT постарался немного описать происходящее, спрашивайте если не понятно.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Вы мой кумир)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ другое дело.Спасибо большое

Comment: @Demon__ANT да ладно Вам, уверен что полно тут талантов, 90% из них просто ничего не пишут, только читают, сам в засаде сидел 3 года, не меньше, активно отвечать начал только недавно, когда под новый год AlexandrTT конкурс поо елочку сделал. сейчас посмотрел у меня за весь период с момента регистрации было 100 ответов, до начала 2019 сейчас 702

Comment: @doox911 Я обычный программист, просто уже давно. Вы даже представить себе не можете на сколько огромная пропасть между мной и теми у кого я пытаюсь учиться.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а  `d3` как масштаб учесть? А то точка вылетает за пределы) https://ibb.co/8XG5zhx

Comment: @doox911 лучше ссылкой на кодепен

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, https://codepen.io/doox911/pen/VJwQxO

Comment: @doox911 Вы добавляете точку в слой, у которого стоит `translate(50,50)`, необходимо это учитывать

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, странно, я делал `translate(50,50)`, а чтобы вернуть кружок в центр вычитаю 53, почему? И у меня не получается замкнуть путь. Как после добавления точек дописать команду `Z`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94754/discussion-between-doox911-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Comment: @Suvitruf кстати это иногда очень не удобно - в мобильном приложении so нет чата

Comment: @StrangerintheQ на Android есть о_О

Answer (score 6):

Можно найти расстояние от точки до прямой без итераций, через [длину ортогональной проекции](http://algolist.ru/maths/geom/distance/pointline.php). Для этого достаточно немного доработать `belongsToTheSide`

```
//находим нормализованный вектор направления прямой
//если одна прямая используется много раз - можно вычислить единожды 
dirx = line.x2 - line.x1;
diry = line.y2 - line.y1;
len = Math.sqrt(dirx * dirx + diry * diry);
dirx = dirx / len;
diry = diry / len; 
//находим расстояние (знак говорит об ориентации, если расстояние больше нужного порога
dist = (x - line.x1) * diry - (y-line.y1) * dirx;
```

Comment: а где у автора итерации?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q У автора их как раз нет, но потенциально могут появиться ;)

Comment: могут, но мы слегка разные задачи рашаем, у автора конечно в вопросе отрезок, а мой ответ для полилинии или другой кривой, представленной `svg` `path`

Comment: Эт я понял, только не присматривался - как у Вас решено с немонотонностью расстояния до разных отрезков?

Comment: ну это не мой алгоритм, это подсмотрено у mike bostock, тут несколько все проще, используется встроенная функция, getPointAtLength. сначала при помощи нее большИм шагом выбирается точка-кандидат, а потом пространство рядом с ней прощупывается в обе стороны

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Теперь всё ясно. Заплюсовал.