# Расширить зону нажатия на полосу

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть тонкая полоска, ширину полоски менять нельзя. Курсор сложно навести на полосу, можно-ли увеличить зону нажатия на полосу не увеличивая саму полосу?

Возможно ли такое сделать?

```js
function ChangeColor() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("line")[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.line {
  background-color: red;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line" onClick="ChangeColor()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: повесьте клик на контейнер и увеличивайте его, а линию не трогайте

Comment: необходимо либо добавлять еще одну невидимую но толстую область поверх линии, либо считать расстояние от курсора до линии и тогда менять курсор и обрабатывать клик, но уже на документе...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в `.line` псевдоэлемент.
Видно его не будет, а вот target от родителя перейдёт к нему.

(p.s. сделал ему фон, чтобы видеть зону таргета)

```js
function ChangeColor() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("line")[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.line {
  background-color: red;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.line::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,.15)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line" onClick="ChangeColor()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вполне рабочий вариант =)

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно увеличить активную область, посчитав расстояние от курсора до линии.

Если линия не прямая - [решение будет сложнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/989989/188366)

```js
container.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  container.style.cursor = isTooClose(e.y ) ? 'pointer' : 'default'
})

container.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (isTooClose(e.y)) line.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${Math.random()*360},65%,65%)`;
})

function isTooClose(y){
  return Math.abs(y - line.getBoundingClientRect().y) <10;
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

#line {
  background-color: red;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="line"></div>
</div>
```