# Как выбрать ближайшую полилинию?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, autocad

Имеется два списка с большим количеством объектов 
List **listPlynes**
List **listPoints**
Необходимо от каждой точки построить отрезок по нормали к ближайшей полилинии.

Никак не додуматься каким образом это реализовать. По идее пройтись foreach по точкам и от каждой строить отрезки, но никак не смозговать как выбирать ближайшую полилинию..

Comment: Как заданы полилинии? (Что конкретно хранится в `listPlynes`)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko очевидно точки этой полилинии

Comment: может быть Вам будет это интересно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/989971/

Comment: В listPlynes хранятся объекты типа Polyline.                                         
   foreach (ObjectId idPoly in idsPoly)                                                                                           {
    Polyline acPoly = (Polyline)tr.GetObject(idPoly, OpenMode.ForRead);
                    listPlynes.Add(acPoly);
}

Comment: Простым перебором пробовали? Цикл по точкам из listPoints. Внутренний цикл по полилиниям из listPlines. Применяем метод полилинии GetClosestPointTo к текущей точке. Вычисляем расстояние между найденной точкой и текущей. Берём ту полилинию, у которой это расстояние окажется наименьшим. Если количество точек и полилиний - не миллионы, должно за вполне адекватное время обработать.