# Как в сформированный путь добавить линию?

Tags: d3.js

Формирую путь:

```
const line = d3.line()
  // .curve(d3.curveLinearClosed)
  .x(d => x_scale(d.x))
  .y(d => y_scale(d.y));

const path  = svg_DS.append('path')
  .datum(opt_points)
  .attr('fill', 'transparent')
  .attr('class','glass')
  .attr('d', line );
```

Храню данные об изменении фигуры так (массив):

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Содержание объекта:

```
{
  x: 4
  y: 4
}
```

Соответственно, после какого либо изменения добавляется объект с координатами в массив. Проблема заключается в том, что линия дорисовывается без команды `M` (переместится). Как мне в `D3`, имея массив точек добавлять команду `M` ?

Comment: я в экзотических случаях ручками путь составляю

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, т.е. штаткой никак? Только костыли?

Comment: я чесслово плохо понял что не так

Comment: @StrangerintheQ например, нарисовали мы квадрат, а потом кликнули на его границах, между точками надо дорисовать линию, в `d` тега `path`. Т.е. обновить `d`. Без `d3` это делал примерно так: `M0 0 L1 1 1 0 Z M10 10 L10 11 10 15 Z`

Comment: а как понять между какими точками добавлять?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/967235/188366

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, надо изучить)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95032/discussion-between-doox911-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Comment: после изменения `data` заново вызовите `.attr('d', line )`;