# Как верстают изогнутые линии?

Tags: css, css3

Как верстаются такие кривые линии между иконками? Или такое с помощью svg/png можно сделать? Знаю, что можно при помощи `position: absolute;` делать, относительно родительского блока, но это криво. Какие есть варианты?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `svg-path` вам поможет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/966870/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85/967235#967235

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/966496/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/966637#966637

Answer (score 1):

Подобные линии удобно будет рисовать в векторном редакторе (например, InkScape). Можете прямо образец подложить и поверх него рисовать. Результат можно экспортировать в виде SVG-файла.