# Бегущая строка на css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Мой пример бегущей строки:

```css
.main {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.second {
  display: inline-flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.main:hover .second span {
  animation: ticker 6s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  1)
  <div class='second'>
    <span>
    lorem ipsum Ea tempora cumque rerum iure.
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Как можно усовершенствовать, что бы независимо от длинные текста всегда прокручивалось до конца строки и потом обратно. Сейчас прокручивать больше чем надо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/966874/188366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```css
#marquee {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px dotted #999;
}
```

```html
<div id="marquee">
  <marquee behavior="scroll" weight="150" loop="infinity" truespeed="200" scrolldelay="200" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">
    <div id='mylist' class='garage-title'></div>Очень длинный текст
  </marquee>
</div>
```